# Sprite Kit player can still leave screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, boundary

I've been trying to prevent my sprite that is controlled by a UIPanGestureRecognizer from leaving the screen. I've tried creating this with this code but the player is still able to leave the screen.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;

    player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"thePlayer.png"];
    player.size = CGSizeMake(35, 35);
    player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    player.name = kPlayerName;
    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:player.size.width/2];
    player.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    player.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    player.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory | wallCategory;
    player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory | bonusCategory;
    [self addChild:player];
    }

 - (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
   [super didMoveToView:view];
   if (!pan) {
    pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(dragPlayer:)];
    pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    pan.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}
}

-(void)dragPlayer: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
CGPoint trans = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
SKAction *moveAction =  [SKAction moveByX:trans.x y:-trans.y  duration:0];
[player runAction:moveAction];
[gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to set `player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;`

Comment: When I set it to YES it does stop at the boundary, but if I drag fast enough the player can still "jump" over the border :/

Comment: If you are setting the position explicilty using touches, then it defeats the point of using SKPhysicsBody. You can explicilty validate the position there/

Comment: Can you show dragPlayer: method?